# Ajouter la fonction de colorier le texte — Adding feature to colour the text

Tags: support, formatting, markdown

Malheureusement je n'ai pas assez de renommée alors je ne peux qu'écrire ici. Est-ce que l'option de colorier le texte peut être rendue disponible ici — il y en a sur Math Stack Exchange ? Le gras, l'italique et la boîte orange actuellement ne sont pas suffisants parfois…

**RÉVISION** —————— **Si colorier le text ici est impossible, peut-on ajouter cette fonction ?**
Je sais que ce sera parfaitment utile. Exemple —— [Cette réponse de Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3013/2345) est parfaitement bien. Comme tous sont noirs, j'ai du mal à la lire. Chaque paragraphe traite d'une différent part de la phrase, du coup TROP difficile de les distinguer.

Autre exemple —— [Traduction de « the instrument is retained with the works » dans une licence d'utilisation](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/traduction-de-the-instrument-is-retained-with-the-works-dans-une-licence-du)

---

Alas, I don't have enough rep, so I can only write here.  Is there an option to colour the text available here — there is on Math Stack Exchange?  The existing bold, italic, and the orange box aren't enough sometimes.

Comment: La même question sur le Méta global: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor. Et n'oublions pas que couleur n'est pas seulement le meilleur moyen de rendre un texte moche, c'est aussi une source d'[in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness)acce[ssi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindness)bil[ité](http://www.afb.org/Section.aspx?FolderID=2&SectionID=57&TopicID=167&DocumentID=2175).

Answer (score 3):

Ces fonctionnalités sont fournies via le formatage mathématique (MathJax), qui n'est disponible que sur les sites où l'on utilise habituellement des notations mathématiques. Sur French Language & Usage, seules les [fonctionnalités de base](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) sont disponibles.

Pour signaler qu'un fragment est incorrect, on peut utiliser `<s>` (barré : “*strike*”), qui n'est documenté que de manière [très indirecte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites). Il est habituel d'indiquer une phrase incorrecte en la commençant par un astérisque. On peut combiner les deux.

> * Cette phrase contient un mot <s>incorrecte</s>.

```
\* Cette phrase contient un mot <s>incorrecte</s>.
```

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci. Même si Meta StackOverflow rejette les couleurs, peut-on le faire ici  —— ou Meta StackOverflow est final ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: De plus, l'usage des couleurs ne rend pas nécessairement et toujours "un texte moche" et "une source d'inaccessibilité"! Si l'usage est bonne ? Voyez http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152183. Voyez aussi les 2 questions dans ma question, dans lesquelles les couleurs aideraient EXTREMEMENT.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: De plus, est-il plus facile d'ajouter les couleurs ici ou le MATHJAX ? Pour lequel est-ce que je devrais me battre ?